# How to count distinct numbers at each row and make a new data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

```
mydata
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    3    2    3    3    2    3    3    2     3
[2,]    3    3    2    3    3    2    3    3    2     3
[3,]    1    3    2    3    3    2    3    3    2     3
[4,]    1    3    2    3    3    2    3    3    2     3
[5,]    1    3    2    3    3    2    3    3    2     3
```

I would like to create new data frame  with three column by counting the total number of distinct numbers in each row .
The expected outcome should be

```
>newdata    
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    3    7
[2,]    0    3    7
[3,]    1    3    6
[4,]    1    3    6
[5,]    1    3    6
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(mydata)` in the question, like this it's difficult to reproduce the example. With `dput` we can to copy&paste the data into an R session..

Comment: try `table(c(row(mydata)), c(mydata))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` with `table`

```
table(rep(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), ncol(mydata)), c(mydata))
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(c(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), .Dim = c(5L, 10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ben provides a great answer, and then the trick is to wrap his table with `as.data.frame.matrix()` to get the desired result:

```
# example data
mat <- matrix(c(3,3,1,1,1,rep(3,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,10),
              rep(2,5),rep(3,10),rep(2,5),rep(3,5)), 
              nrow=5, ncol=10)

# count values by row
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(row(mat),mat))

# confirm result
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ 1: int  0 0 1 1 1
 $ 2: int  3 3 3 3 3
 $ 3: int  7 7 6 6 6
```